# How can I test my UWP app on Windows 10 Mobile when my dev OS is Windows 10 Home?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp, virtual-machine

I want you to think creatively on this question.

I'm running Windows 10 Home edition, which as you know do not have Hyper-V and thus cannot run the Windows Phone 10 Emulator. I don't have a physical Windows 10 phone. How can I, for the minimum cost, test and preferrably debug my UWP app on a Windows Phone 10 emulator?

I tried setting up Windows 2017 Server + Visual Studio 2017 Community on an Amazon EC2 instance, and after a couple of hour of configuring I'm met with

```
Editing this project is not supported on a server operating system. Please use a Windows 10 client to continue development of your Universal Windows app project.
```

..so that was a dead end. Other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to upgrade to Windows 10 Pro (or Enterprise) to have access to Hyper-V and be able to run the Windows Phone 10 emulator (or get an actual phone device). In my opinion, upgrading your Home license to Pro will probably be the cheapest solution long term anyway.

> A copy of Windows 10 Home will run $119, while Windows 10 Pro will
>   cost $199. For those who wish to upgrade from the Home edition to the
>   Pro edition, a Windows 10 Pro Pack will cost $99.

Source: https://www.cnet.com/news/microsoft-prices-single-windows-10-licenses-at-119-for-home-199-for-pro/

You can NOT run a Windows Phone 10 emulator on Amazon/Azure since they use virtualized machines and they don't provide nested virtualization. You can make a Windows 10 VM on Azure for developer purposes, but you won't be able to run the phone emulator.

[image]